# hooking up uvm_analysis_export and write function

Tags: uvm

I've learned two design patterns of writing a subscriber:

1) Derive from `uvm_subscriber`, override the `write` function, which is then called over the built-in analysis port

2) derive from `uvm_component`, install an `uvm_analysis_export` and `uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo`, connect them and process in the `run_phase`

I'm wondering about the following. If I do *not* derive from `uvm_subscriber`, but from `uvm_component`, install an `uvm_analysis_export` and write a `write` function, which is to be called over the `uvm_analysis_export` by the corresponding port, how do I do hook up the `uvm_analysis_export` to the `write`? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to "hook up the `uvm_analysis_export` to the `write`". Instead, you need to derive from `uvm_component`, install a `uvm_analysis_imp` (an `imp` not an `export`) and write a `write` function.

An `imp` is the endpoint; (with the subscriber pattern) it is this that calls the `write` method. An `export` is a waypoint; it can only be connected to another `export` or `imp`.

If we look at the source code for the `uvm_subscriber` class, we can see how to do it:

```
virtual class uvm_subscriber #(type T=int) extends uvm_component;

  typedef uvm_subscriber #(T) this_type;

  // Port: analysis_export
  //
  // This export provides access to the write method, which derived subscribers
  // must implement.

  uvm_analysis_imp #(T, this_type) analysis_export;

  // Function: new
  //
  // Creates and initializes an instance of this class using the normal
  // constructor arguments for <uvm_component>: ~name~ is the name of the
  // instance, and ~parent~ is the handle to the hierarchical parent, if any.

  function new (string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
    analysis_export = new("analysis_imp", this);
  endfunction

  // Function: write
  //
  // A pure virtual method that must be defined in each subclass. Access
  // to this method by outside components should be done via the
  // analysis_export.

  pure virtual function void write(T t);

endclass
```

I am not quite sure why you'd want to do this, because as you can see, you'd be pretty much just rewriting what's already done for you in `uvm_subscriber`. I guess by asking the question you've learnt something and I've refreshed some knowledge in answering it.